# Indexing list to find duplicate characters in string (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, indexing

So my program is asking the user to input a list of strings and then sort out the strings where if the first letter is repeated again in the same string, it stores it into another list. Here is what I have so far.

```
iput = []
i = 0
final = []

while i < 1:
    iput += [input('Enter words here: ')]
    if not iput[-1]:
        i += 1

i = 0
z = 1
while i < len(iput) - 1:
    print(i)
    while iput[i][0] != iput[i][z]:
        if z == len(iput[i]):
            break
        z += 1

    i += 1

print(final)
print(iput)
```

I keep getting a "string index out of range" error and can't think of a way to add the strings that have the requirements stated above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your problem ? I realy dont understand what it is?

Comment: The program prompts the user to enter a list of words and stores in a list only those words whose first letter occurs again elsewhere in the word (e.g., "Baboon").  Once the user enters a null string, the program should print the elements stored in the list, one word per line.

Answer (score 0):

Your `z` will grow to values longer than the length of `iput`.

You break the inner loop when `z` reaches the length of `iput` but never reset it in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will first access the out-of-bounds index, followed by checking to see if the index is out of bounds. Make your check come before you access the out-of-bounds index.

```
while i < len(iput) - 1:
    print(i)
    while z != len(iput[i]) and iput[i][0] != iput[i][z]:
        z += 1

    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you should check every list element with all elemtns you should reset `z` every while loop so add:

`z = 1`

after ending while loop :

```
while i < len(iput) - 1:
    print(i)
    while iput[i][0] != iput[i][z]:
        if z == len(iput[i]):
            break
        z += 1
   z = 1
   i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's about `z` becoming one too big: you keep incrementing it in a loop but access `iput[i][z]` before you check whether `z` has become equal to `iput[i]`. Once it's equal, it's too late, though: Python string indexes are 0-based, meaning that your `z` may at most become `len(iput[i]) - 1`.

While that was an analysis of what actually happens in your code, let me say that this code is rather unpythonic in that it spells out a lot of mechanical details that give opportunities for this kind of mistakes. There are language constructs in Python that allow you to express the same things more concisely (and more efficiently as well).

```
iput = []
final = []

while True:
    iput += [input('Enter words here: ')]
    if not iput[-1]:
        break

for i, line in enumerate(iput):
    print(i)
    for c in line[1:]:
        if c == line[0]:
            final.append(line)
            break

print(final)
print(iput)
```

Even more Pythonic, but less reminiscent of your algorithm:

```
final = [line for line in iput if line[0] in line[1:]]
```